# Wordpress - How to defer parsing of Javascript to execute after DOM loads?

Tags: wordpress, deferred-execution

I am using wp_enqueue_scripts() to set my JS files and I am putting them in the footer using the last parameter

But testing in [gtmetrix](http://gtmetrix.com/), I still see that I need to defer parsing of Javascript.

How do I defer parsing of Javascript to execute after DOM loads in Wordpress? Is there a parameter perhaps to wp_enqueue_scripts() that can do this?

Answer (score 2):

First if all, [wp_enqueue_scripts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) will only load scripts in the footer if you set the fifth parameter. Even if you do that, if the file contains content that will execute without user interaction then you should be wrapping that in a [jQuery.ready() call](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

The latter part has nothing to do with wordpress. That's a basic web development rule.